# Accessing an array from the stack

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

I am new to assembly programming and trying to write a simple assembly level code where the intention is to send the base address of an array to a stack and access it within a procedure to find out the smallest element  The array is a 5 byte array with 5 elements. Unfortunately after passing the address of the array within stack I am unable to access it back through BP register. The code snippet is as below and I am using the 8086 emulator. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
START:
 MOV AX,@data
 MOV DS,AX

 ;MOV AX,STACK
 ;MOV SS,AX

 ;MOV SP,OFFSET TOP_STACK
 MOV BX,OFFSET ARRAY   
 
 
 
 PUSH BX
 PUSH BP
 
 MOV BP,SP
 MOV BX,[BP+4]
 MOV AX,[BX]
```

Till the second last line I am able to follow the execution and the system is showing the correct address of the data segment. However when the last line executes I expect that the first element of the array will be available ( i.e 10 ) but in reality I get only 0.

Here is the full code:

```
.stack 100h

.data
ARRAY DB 10H,05H,20H,60H,35H

.code

START:
 MOV AX,@data
 MOV DS,AX

 MOV BX,OFFSET ARRAY   
 
 PUSH BX
 PUSH BP
 
 CALL PROC1 ; CALLING POINT OF THE PROCEDURE
 
 MOV AH,4CH 
 INT 21H

PROC1 PROC NEAR
      
      MOV BP,SP
      MOV BX,word[BP+3]  ; ARRAY BASE ADDRESS  
      XOR AX,AX     
      MOV AL,BYTE[BX]
      
      MOV CX,04
SMALL:   
      
      MOV AH,BYTE[BX]
      CMP AL,AH 
      
      JG SWAP
      INC BX  
      
      LOOP SMALL
      JMP EXITPROC      
SWAP:
      MOV AL,AH
      INC BX
      JMP SMALL

EXITPROC:
  
   POP BP  
   POP BX
   
        RET
        PROC1 ENDP 

CODE ENDS
END START
```

Comment: To get the value pushed by `push bx` here you would need `mov bx, word [bp + 2]` because, in your example, there is no return address between the stack slot used by the `push bx` and the stack address used from `bp` by your `mov bx`. Also if you have a 5-byte array composed of 5 elements, ie one byte per element, you need `mov al, byte [bx]` not `mov ax`. Either put `xor ax, ax` before the `mov al` or put `cbw` after the `mov al`.

Comment: Hello , thanks for the reply.  Two follow up queries .  Could you please help me understand the first part ?  Why do I need to  use word[bp+2]  ? secondly   When you use the qualifier byte , like you mentioned byte[bx]  which portion of bx ie the higher order byte or the lower order byte would be returned ?  I will try to incorporate this and would let you know the result . Thanks once again for providing the insight.

Comment: The `word [bp + 2]` is because `bp` equals `sp`, and `word [bp]` points to the most recently pushed 16-bit value (from `push bp`) and just after that (add offset `+ 2` which is the size of a 16-bit word) you have the `word [bp + 2]` which is the second-most recently pushed word (from `push bx`). If between the two `push` instructions you had a `call some_function_name` (and the `push bp` was at the start of that function) then between the old `bp` value and the pushed `bx` value there would be a 16-bit word `ip` near return address so `word [bp + 4]` would be right to address the pushed `bx`.

Comment: To get a "portion of `bx`" you'd use either `bl` (least significant byte) or `bh` (most significant byte). Using `[bx]` gets something from the byte-addressable memory **at the address** read from `bx`. Byte addressable means each address increment refers to 1 byte. Therefore if you load a 16-bit word (like `mov ax, [bx]` which is the same as `mov ax, word [bx]` -- register `ax` implies `word`) it'll be composed of two bytes. For example if the memory at address 200h held 55h then at 201h it held AAh and you have `bx` = 200h and you load `word [bx]` you will get AA55h. And, `byte [bx]` is 55h.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation . I think  the mistake was although I am aware that  BX and BP are both operating on  16 bit word but I was calculating the position of the address in stack wrongly . My learning from this discussion is usage of the qualifier byte and word which I was not aware .  BTW I have made the changes and the program segment runs properly.

Comment: A final query  ,  in the above program  after pushing  details to the stack  the code looks like     MOV BX,OFFSET ARRAY   
 
 PUSH BX
 PUSH BP
 
 
 CALL PROC1 ; CALLING POINT OF THE PROCEDURE
 
 MOV AH,4CH 
 INT 21H

Comment: Now   in the procedure , at the end,  there is a RET call  post which  the control is going to the begining to the start of the program and not going to the next statement after the CALL statement . In many places I am reading that this might happen  if BP is not  popped . But I have done that , so not sure what is the issue here . Could you please comment .

Comment: PROC1 PROC NEAR
      
      MOV BP,SP
      MOV BX,word[BP+3]  ; ARRAY BASE ADDRESS  
      XOR AX,AX     
      MOV AL,BYTE[BX]
      
      MOV CX,04
SMALL:   
      
      MOV AH,BYTE[BX]
      CMP AL,AH 
      
      JG SWAP
      INC BX  
      
      LOOP SMALL
      JMP EXITPROC      
SWAP:
      MOV AL,AH
      INC BX
      JMP SMALL

EXITPROC:
  
   POP BP  
   POP BX
   
        RET
        PROC1 ENDP 

CODE ENDS
END START         this is how the  procedure looks

Comment: Please edit your question with the new code or make a new question (linking back to this one) with the code, as reading code in comments without linebreaks is very difficult.

Comment: The full code added .  Could you please comment as to why  the control goes to the beginning of  START :  instead of the statement after the call PROC1  ? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Your pushing and popping is unbalanced. Recall that `call` is like `push next ip` plus `jmp`. So in your new example you will push, in this order, `bx`, `bp`, and a near return `ip`. Also consider that `retn` is like `pop ip`. Now, you're trying to pop the stack in the order `bp` then `bx` then `ip`. The stack is LIFO, so the push order needs to be exactly the pop order in reverse. `word [bp + 3]` is completely wrong; there is no way (other than manual memory addressing) to ever push into a slot that's an odd amount of bytes from the stack pointer. Besides you should push `bp` in the function.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the explanation . I have been able to figure out the mistake. The PUSH sequence was  BX,BP and the procedure call was made .  Now correct me if I am wrong . with every push a word gets pushed onto the stack  and also with a procedure call. So what I am noticing in the EMU stack display the SP after the 2 push plus one procedure call  it has moved 3 words . Hence to reach address of the array  bp+3 has been used .  While popping I  forgot that the return address was associated  with the call of the procedure . So now once the POP is relocated after the call stmt the code works.

Comment: "with every push a word gets pushed onto the stack and also with a procedure call" - Yes. "Hence to reach address of the array bp+3 has been used." - This is incorrect. First, 3 words are 6 bytes so by your logic you should use `+ 6` not `+ 3`, as each word increments the address by 2. Additionally, you don't want to access the slot that's fourth from the stack top but rather the third one: `word [bp + 0]` is first, `word [bp + 2]` is second, `word [bp + 4]` is third, `word [bp + 6]` is fourth. (The index into the stack is zero-based, itself like a kind of array.)

Comment: Ok now I get it .  So within the square bracket the calculation still remains like a single byte slot .  So in my case this should be  [bp+4] . Surprisingly the program gave me still  the correct output as bp+3 was still in the third slot .  Thanks a ton for your explanation. Is there a  good tutorial or a book or some resources that you could point me to? I really want to learn this  deep like you . Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: `[bp + 3]` may just so happen to give the correct results because of the values in the registers and the addresses of your variables. That does not make it correct. The address calculation that you can do in brackets (or outside them too, if you eventually dereference a calculated number as an address) is always byte-addressable, so adding 1 makes an address point 1 byte farther than before. 16-bit words are stored into two 8-bit bytes. When I refer to stack slots on the 8086 I'm considering one slot as word-sized; however, you can call bytes anywhere in memory "memory slots" too.

Comment: As for references, you can look at [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) on here. You can also browse [my website](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/) which includes a bunch of 86/DOS assembly programming projects, some of which have documentation and releases, and all of which are free software with sources included. Most of these sources can be browsed in hgweb repos online. There's also [an instruction reference](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-insref) (linked from the tag wiki too) and [a guide on commenting and style](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-acegals).